# Regex to find if a specific character exists odd times in String

Tags: java, regex, string

Is there any way to write a `regular expression` in Java  which finds if a `String` contains an odd number of a specific character i.e. `"a"`? I have done it writing more verbose code, using namely the following method:

```
public static boolean hasEvenNumber(String s) {
        int count = 0;

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^a)*(a)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find())
            count++;

        if (count % 2 != 0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

If for example one passes the String `"jsadaajaaikadjasl"` as parameter, then it retuns true, since it contains 7 `"a"`. Is there a more elegant way to achieve it using only a `regex` and checking it like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(...);
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if(m.matches())
   return true;
```

?

Comment: Why do you need a regex? A simple loop can do that.

Comment: `!s.replaceAll("[^*a[^a]a[^a]*|[^a]+", "").isEmpty();`

Comment: I know it is not the best thing to restrict the solution ways, but exactly for that reason I am asking. I know there are plenty ways to do it, but I am interested in the way puts it through only with a regex.

Comment: There's no reason to use a regex for this

Comment: I don't understand how a regex solution could be less verbose than the looping solution and it would be MUCH more cryptic--it would be plain mean to use regex here.  the operative part of the java code would be for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) if(s.charAt(i)=='a')n++; Most expressions given here are nearly as long as that themselves!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a pattern that matches an even count like `"(?:[^a]*a[^a]*a)*"` the add another occurrence, `(?:[^a]*a[^a]*a)*[^a]*a[^a]`. Now if matcher.`matches` returns `true` you have an odd number of occurrences.

Comment: You need to add anchors for the regex to test the whole string :) Otherwise, use `.matches`

Comment: I said “use `matches`”. But I forgot the repeating. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you want to use regex here (and I am not sure if I wan't to know) but you can try with `[^a]*a([^a]*a[^a]*a)*[^a]*`.

It means

```
[^a]*            # zero or more non-a characters 
                 # (in case string starts with non-a character)
a                # one "a" character 
([^a]*a[^a]*a)*  # two "a" characters preceded by zero or more non-a characters
                 # (this will match any numbers of "..a..a" "pairs")
[^a]*            # zero or more non-a characters 
                 # (in case string ends with non-a character)
```

In case you would like to match even numbers of `a` just remove `[^a]*a` from start or regex.

```
System.out.println("jsadaajaaikadjasl".matches("[^a]*a([^a]*a[^a]*a)*+[^a]*"));
System.out.println("jasadaajaaikadjasl".matches("[^a]*a([^a]*a[^a]*a)*+[^a]*"));
```

output:

```
true
false
```

---

Instead of regex you could use this simple method which will iterate over all string characters, compare them with searched one and each time when it find match flip `boolean` flag from `odd` to `even` or vice versa.

```
public static boolean hasOdd(String s, char character) {
    boolean response = false;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray())
        if (c == character)
            response = !response;
    return response;
}

//...

System.out.println(hasOdd("jsadaajaaikadjasl", 'a'));//true
System.out.println(hasOdd("jasadaajaaikadjasl", 'a'));//false
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just count the characters and check that the String doesn't start with the character in question. You could use Apache Commons [CharsetUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/CharSetUtils.html) for this:

```
public static boolean hasOddNumber(String s, char c) {
  boolean hasOddNumber = false; 
  if (s.charAt(0) != c){
    hasOddNumber = CharSetUtils.count(s, c) % 2 != 0;
  }
  return hasOddNumber;
```

Also, I'd change the method name to `hasOddNumber` since your question implies that you want to know if a String has an *odd* number of occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a regex then this code should work:

```
String str = "abadaa";
boolean isAOdd = str.matches("^[^a]*a(?=(([^a]*a){2})*[^a]*$).*$"); // false

str = "abadaacad";
isAOdd = str.matches("^[^a]*a(?=(([^a]*a){2})*[^a]*$).*$"); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Odd: `"^[^a]*(a[^a]*a[^a]*)*a[^a]*$"`

Even: `"^([^a]*a[^a]*a[^a]*)+$"`

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:([^a]*a[^a]*a[^a]*)*)
```

matches even numbers of `a` and

```
[^a]*a(?:([^a]*a[^a]*a[^a]*)*)
```

matches odd numbers of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Here should be a working example of what you are trying to achive.

```
public static boolean hasEvenNumber(String s) {
    int counter = 0;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([aA])?{1,}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        if (m.group().equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
            counter++;
    }
    return (counter != 0 && counter%2==0);
}
```

Comment: Result will be the same for `"aba"` and `"abaa"`

Comment: So true. Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([aA])?{1,}"); should fix the problem

Comment: This would include occurrences of any character. `"1"` -> true, `"12"`->false.

Comment: Hehe. Ok. Lets add check for a in the group perhaps. Updated example

Comment: It works but only because you are checking each result of previously created chaos. All your regex does is finding either empty string (for not `a` character) or `a`. So your regex is not helping but making everything more complicated. Easier would be iterating over each character (for example by using `string.charAt(i)`) and compare it with `a`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "jsadaajaaikadjasl";
    System.out.println(hasEvenNumber(s,"a"));
}

public static boolean hasEvenNumber(String s, String letter) {

    int count = s.length() - s.replaceAll(letter, "").length();
    return count % 2 == 0 ? false : true ;
}
```